# Mac crashing suddenly and restart

Tags: macos, mac, crash, shutdown

My Mac keeps on crashing around 5 times a day which is very annoying. It just turns off all of a sudden and than start again... Crash log is provided below. Any idea as to what may cause this?

```
    Interval Since Last Panic Report:  932654 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          8
Anonymous UUID:                    56779F7C-88A6-E421-B2DD-F955F3A25E9A

Sat Jun  8 13:54:45 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa06537f2): NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff809ca1e000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff809606b7a0 : 0xffffff801fe1d626 
0xffffff809606b810 : 0xffffff7fa06537f2 
0xffffff809606b8d0 : 0xffffff7fa07503b9 
0xffffff809606b930 : 0xffffff7fa075042e 
0xffffff809606b9a0 : 0xffffff7fa0a76c82 
0xffffff809606bad0 : 0xffffff7fa0776fe8 
0xffffff809606bb10 : 0xffffff7fa065b567 
0xffffff809606bbc0 : 0xffffff7fa065905a 
0xffffff809606bdc0 : 0xffffff7fa065a0c5 
0xffffff809606bea0 : 0xffffff7fa05f8aba 
0xffffff809606bef0 : 0xffffff7fa20c80df 
0xffffff809606bf40 : 0xffffff7fa20c71e7 
0xffffff809606bf60 : 0xffffff801fe3dcfe 
0xffffff809606bfb0 : 0xffffff801feb2977 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1)[A26D2A3D-C06F-3A0F-BCFF-901A98C93C3D]@0xffffff7fa05f6000->0xffffff7fa0903fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7fa045a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[38C214C0-83C8-3594-8A4C-DC6AC3FEC163]@0xffffff7fa05e2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[74E3E50F-E50A-3073-8C96-06F854292A91]@0xffffff7fa059f000
         com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(8.1)[5F021999-8B18-3BD5-9B98-90617E638A63]@0xffffff7fa0911000->0xffffff7fa0c32fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.0)[A26D2A3D-C06F-3A0F-BCFF-901A98C93C3D]@0xffffff7fa05f6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7fa045a000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(100.12.87)[A7004F02-7D39-3398-8BD3-729DCC404E5F]@0xffffff7fa20c6000->0xffffff7fa20d5fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7fa045a000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.3.0d51)[2C131EAF-F74C-39D1-A702-A499B39C293C]@0xffffff7fa1032000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[38C214C0-83C8-3594-8A4C-DC6AC3FEC163]@0xffffff7fa05e2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[74E3E50F-E50A-3073-8C96-06F854292A91]@0xffffff7fa059f000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12D78

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 3EB7D8A7-C2D3-32EC-80F4-AB37D61492C6
Kernel slide:     0x000000001fc00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801fe00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1689732180630
last loaded kext at 239002001884: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   1.8 (addr 0xffffff7fa2205000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 142236835942: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5 (addr 0xffffff7fa0e60000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0
com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.7.2
com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt   0.0.74
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   75.19
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.87
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.3.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.1.0
com.apple.GeForce   8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.3f3
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   614.20.16
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.0b1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  170.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  235.29
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.1.3f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    8.1.0
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.3.0d51
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   522.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.2
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.3f3 11349, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0236, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0xfa113000 / 7
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa130000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Ext HDD 1021, 0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.), 0x1021, 0xfd130000 / 5
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: Did you try safe mode? CMD-R !

Answer (score 1):

Try the Safe mode first to verify.

This is a widely known problem

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa06537f2): NVRM[0/1:0:0]

(NVRM)=Nvidia

with published solution's:

You have a bad NVIDIA GPU.

[image]

Print out your kernel panic and [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) article and take your machine into your local Apple Store or an AASP so that they can replace the logic board. You might be lucky and get it done at no cost to you.

In some cases this is also related to a graphic switching to external monitor. So try the Safe mode and see if it happens.

Comment: Can that be the cause even if I don't have a Nvidia graphics card? My graphics says:   Intel HD Graphics 288 MB @Buscar 웃

Comment: What are you talking about? you do have the NVIDIA! It shows it in your system profile here>>>>> Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB

Comment: But my system profiler says I have the Intel graphics.....

Comment: You have 2 Graphics cards according to your system profile. The Build in Intel and the add on NVIDIA. I added the screenshot of your system information showing 2 graphics cards.

Comment: Hi, I sent my computert to the apple service provider and they claim its a Hard Disk problem. Do you think that could be the cause of tne problem?