# How do I run virtual machines in Parallels Lite on Mojave?

Tags: mojave, parallels-desktop

I downloaded Parallels Lite from the App Store. Even though Parallels Lite claims to be free if you want to run Linux virtual machines, the only thing I see is this:

[image]

This is what the help says:

> ## Choose How to Use Parallels Desktop Lite
>
> When you launch Parallels Desktop Lite for the first time, you need to
>   choose how you're going to use it. Choose one of the following:
>
> - **Windows & Support**. If you choose this option, you will be able to create and run virtual machines with Windows, Linux and any other
>     supported operating system. You will also be able to contact the
>     support team for assistance.
>
>   **Note**: This option is free during a trial period. If you want to continue using Windows or other virtual machines after the trial
>     period expires, you need to purchase a subscription.
> - **Linux only**. If you choose this option, you will be able to create and run only Linux virtual machines. This option is completely
>     free of charge. However, telephone support is not available.
>
> **Important!** Please note that Windows and its license are not included.

<sup>Transcribed from [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsHVy.png) provided by OP.</sup>

but I never saw the window described in the help page. Instead, it took me straight to subscription.

What am I doing wrong? Why am I unable to add a virtual machine?

Comment: No experience with this but I have successfully used the free VirtualBox (by Oracle, formally Sun) App. It is updated regularly and works well, though I have heard that Parallels and VMWare are a bit faster. Possibly a good choice for price sensitive or lighter useage virtualization.

Comment: @SteveChambers no, it doesn't work at all, every time I run Ubuntu from virtualbox, it crashes my mac mini 2018 and it restarts the OS. See here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361418/why-does-virtualbox-crash-macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Parallels forum](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/why-i-cant-use-parallels-lite-w-o-subscription-anymore.346406/), Parallels no longer offers free Linux, even though their Help document says they do...